# Laravel : add new row in model table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, form-submit

I have a user model defined, and I'm trying to add a new user in my database using a form, what is the best and fastest way to do it, I have read something about model forms binding but I think it's just for updating not for adding new rows.

I'm new in Laravel and couldn't find some good tutorials, I must recognize that Laravel documentation is really poor, so any links to some good and well explained tutorials are welcomed. 
Thank you

Comment: You can create a new row as simple as `User::create(Input::all())` when your `$fillable` is properly set in the model. Here is a simple crud tutorial, looks nice, http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Answer (score 25):

Assumed that, you have a `User` model (`app/models/User.php`) the one came with `Laravel` by default, which may look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Now, from a controller (Basically) you may use somethng like this:

```
$user = new user;
$user->username= 'Me';
$user->email = 'me@yahoo.com';
// add more fields (all fields that users table contains without id)
$user->save();
```

There are other ways, for example:

```
$userData = array('username' => 'Me', 'email' => 'me@yahoo.com');
User::create($userData);
```

Or this:

```
User::create(Input::except('_token'));
```

This requires you to use a property in your `User` model like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'email');

    // Or this,  (Read the documentation first before you use it/mass assignment)
    protected $guarded = array();

}
```

Since, you are still new to `Laravel` you may use first example and read about [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment), then you may use the second one if you want.

### Update:

In your controller, you may use `Input::get('formfieldname')` to get the submitted data, for example:

```
$username = Input::get($username);
```

So, you can use these data like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username= $username;
```

Or directly you can use:

```
$user->email = Input::get($email);
$user->save();
```

In the form, you have to set the `form action`, where you'll submit the form and in this case you have to declare a route, for example:

```
Route::post('user/add', array('as' => 'user.add', 'uses' => 'UserController@addUser'));
```

Then in your controller you have to create the method `addUser`, like this:

```
class UserController extends addUser {
    
    // other methods
    
    public function addUser()
    {
        $user = new user;
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->email = Input::get($email);
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

In your form you may use this:

```
Form::open(array('route' => 'user.add'))
```

Read [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/) properly, you can do it easily.

Comment: Exactly, but how I will get the username and the email from the form to the controller, I already tried the Form::open(array('url'=>'url_of_controller')) but didn't worked

Comment: `$user->usaername` --> `$user->username`